# Azcopy: Is it possible do resume a download with a new SAS key

Tags: azure, azcopy

I started downloading a bigger blob of data (around 500GB) yesterday using azcopy. I had it run overnight, and - as these things go when you have big downloads / uploads - my Windows Desktop decided that it has an important update and needs to restart.

Normally, I would have just resumed the download in the morning; however, now I get an authorization error. Likely, because the SAS key expired, so I'd like to give it a new one.

I used the following command for this job:

```
copy https://<blobstore>.blob.core.windows.net/<path>?se=2019-07-18t21%3A59%3A10z&sig=<signature>&sp=rlac&spr=https&srt=sco&ss=b&st=2019-07-11t13%3A59%3A10z&sv=2018-03-28 . --recursive
```

Hence my question: Can I give the incomplete job a new SAS key so that it can resume the download?

Comment: Note that block level resume (i.e. resuming a file download from where it left off) is not supported (https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-azcopy/issues/806). Only directory level (restarting from the begining of a file) is supported - apparently to avoid blob consistency issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution. The command `azcopy jobs resume` allows to specify the arguments `--source-sas` and `--destination-sas`. I could resume the job by supplying a new token:

```
azcopy jobs resume <job-id> --source-sas <sas-token>
```

for example

```
azcopy jobs resume 67739a41-d3c6-204a-5449-9c3f0bd18ce2 --source-sas "?sv=2018-03-28&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacup&se=2019-08-02T21:00:00Z&st=2019-07-12T04:10:24Z&spr=https&sig=<signature>"
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, AzCopy has a re-startable mode. From [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazurestorage/2013/09/07/azcopy-transfer-data-with-re-startable-mode-and-sas-token/):

```
 AzCopy C:\blobData https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/destkey:key /Z:restart.log /s
```

`/Z` is the parameter to turn on the
re-startable mode. ‘restart.log’ is the customer-defined name of the journal file which will be saved in local.

Comment: I tried adding `/Z`, `-Z`, and `--Z`. For /Z I get an error for the wrong number of input arguments (makes sense, I'm on Windows) and for the dash variant azcopy reports that it can't find the symbol. I checked the help and indeed it isn't listed (nor is anything that sounds like I can supply the journal)

Comment: Actually `/Z`is an option for AzCopy V8, but @FirefoxMetzger is using AzCopy V10.